# Why Doesn't Rasag Mention Olives In The Five Fruits From Eretz Yisrael?

Tags: blessing, eretz-yisrael, prayer-book, saadya-gaon

[In his *siddur*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&st=&pgnum=143), Rav Sa`adya haGaon (Rasa"g) mentions only four of the five species of *peroth ha-ilan* which are special to Eress Yisrael, leaving out *zethim* ("olives"). He does so in two places. Further, he does not simply list the other four and leave out olives, rather he precedes his listing of them with the words *huss me-arabaah dhevarim* ("except for these ***four*** things"). This seems to indicate a volitional (i.e. *shitah*-based) reason for doing so.

**Question:** Why does Rasa"g not mention *zethim* in his list of the five *peroth ha-ilan* which Eress Yisrael is known for and which require *Birkath Me-En Shalosh* (i.e. *al ha-ess we-al feri ha-ess*)?

Comment: Possibly related to the question of beracha on olives, since they are primarily grown for oil—and oil (unlike wine) is not drunk on its own.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon If olive oil is drunk on its own as food then it also gets an "Al haPeirot".

Comment: Perhaps he viewed olives as _ba im haseuda_ and left them off because they are usually covered in the birkat hamazon? Note his discussion at the bottom of the page after the linked page.

Comment: "_we-al feri_"  ?

Comment: Did you see the footnote at the other location http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&st=&pgnum=146 ?